# How to require a jwt in front end

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, web-frontend

I know that the server creates the jwt and sends it back to the front-end once user's credentials are authenticated, then the token is stored in the browser local storage. My question is: how can i use pure javascript to check if user has a valid jwt before rendering the page he wants to access and forbid him in case jwt is invalid?

Comment: `how can i use pure javascript to check if user has a valid jwt` you can't if javascript does not run on the server.it's the role of the server to check whether the token is valid or not, not the client. You need to query the server with the token then the server issues a 200 http code if authorization is granted or 403 is authorization if not granted, but the logic needs to be implemented server-side.

Comment: just a little clarification: validating jwt is actually authentication, not authorization. For invalid token you return 401 (confusingly named 'Unauthorized').

Comment: Let's suppose that a user tries to access a url which requires a jwt in my rest api. How can i get this token and send it to server? And case server returns 401 or user doesn't even have a token(he didn't log in) , how could i redirect to another page, since back-end in a rest api doesn't  render templates? I'm not using any js framework or lib

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume that whatever is on the client's side of things is unprotected from the client. That means that whatever you want to render - if it is stored on the client's machine - shouldn't be sensitive information. An example of that is your API, which is why it is usually stored in the backend. In the case that you really want to render your pages from your server, however, look into server-side rendering (SSR).